# Send Multiple Get requests

Tags: java, get

I am writing code to send get requests for a list of URLs. Now, some of the get requests are failing and not returning HTTP Response Code 200. But when I hit the URL for the get request on browser  I am able to download the XML file(which is what should happen). My first question is why does this happening that when I am sending get request from my code, the request fails but it doesnot fail otherwise.

My second question is how can I fix this problem of failed get requests.

Please find below the code sample that I am writing in my code.

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
```

The Exception is:

```
Update:
Response Code : 404
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzakooXyvuA
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ReadMyExcel.sendGet(ReadMyExcel.java:133)
    at ReadMyExcel.readExcel(ReadMyExcel.java:82)
    at ReadMyExcel.main(ReadMyExcel.java:99)
```

Comment: What HTTP status code do you get in response when your code issues the GET request?

Comment: What response codes are being returned if not 200s?  Post your program's debug output as well.

Comment: Have you tried hitting that URL in your browser?  Guess what code is returned?

Comment: yes i hv tried hitting the url in browser. xml is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only work if you authenticate to Google using OAuth2. I have tried accessing the url from my browser and I get the same 404 error message.

You're probably trying to access a feed that is limited to your user account.

Use the [Youtube API Client for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3) and check the [samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java) to learn how to authenticate and make requests to the Youtube API.